# How to Add a Login Screen Before my TabViewController

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, authentication, viewcontroller

So currently I have my AppDelegate set to make my CustomTabBarController the root view controller:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    FIRApp.configure()

    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
    window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

    window?.rootViewController = CustomTabBarController()

    return true
}
```

In my TabBarController.swift file I override the viewDidLoad function with:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Custom view controllers
    let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    let friendsController = ContactsController(collectionViewLayout: layout)
    let recentMessagesNavController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: friendsController)
    recentMessagesNavController.tabBarItem.title = "DMs"
    recentMessagesNavController.tabBarItem.image = UIImage(named: "")

    viewControllers = [recentMessagesNavController, createDummyNavControllerWithTitle("Groups", imageName: ""), createDummyNavControllerWithTitle("Submit", imageName: ""), createDummyNavControllerWithTitle("Search", imageName: ""), createDummyNavControllerWithTitle("Other", imageName: "")]
}
```

Following that my ContactsController.swift file has this:

```
private let cellID = "cellID"
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Navigation bar
    navigationItem.title = "Direct Messages"
    collectionView?.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    collectionView?.alwaysBounceVertical = true
    collectionView?.registerClass(MessageCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: cellID)
    setupData()

    // Fetch messages provided by the fetch controller
    do {
        try fetchedResultsController.performFetch()
    } catch let err {
        print(err)
    }

}
```

I do not currently have a storyboard file as all of my views are created programmatically. I have been trying to add a login screen that will pop up and block the TabBarController if the user is not logged in but I can not figure out the best way to implement this without getting errors. At the moment my SignInViewController does have custom elements created programmatically. What is the method to go about solving my problem?

**Edit for comments:**
Currently my SignInViewController has this:

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {

    if let user = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser {
        self.signedIn(user)
    }

    collectionView?.registerClass(BaseCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: cellID)
    collectionView?.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
    collectionView?.alwaysBounceVertical = false
    tabBarController?.tabBar.hidden = true

    view.addSubview(loginContainerView)
    view.addConstraintWithFormat("H:|[v0]|", views: loginContainerView)
    view.addConstraintWithFormat("V:|[v0]|", views: loginContainerView)
    setupInputComponents()
}

private let cellID = "cellID"
var bottomConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint?

private func setupInputComponents() {
    let loginControls = UIView()
    loginControls.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellowColor()
    loginContainerView.addSubview(emailField)
    loginContainerView.addSubview(passwordField)
    loginContainerView.addSubview(loginButton)
    loginContainerView.addSubview(signUpButton)
    loginContainerView.addSubview(passwordResetButton)
    loginContainerView.addConstraintWithFormat("H:|[v0]|", views: emailField)
    loginContainerView.addConstraintWithFormat("V:|[v0]|", views: emailField)
    loginContainerView.addConstraintWithFormat("H:|[v0]|", views: passwordField)
    loginContainerView.addConstraintWithFormat("V:|[v0]|", views: passwordField)
    loginContainerView.addConstraintWithFormat("H:|[v0]|", views: loginButton)
    loginContainerView.addConstraintWithFormat("V:|[v0]|", views: loginButton)
    loginContainerView.addConstraintWithFormat("H:|[v0]|", views: signUpButton)
    loginContainerView.addConstraintWithFormat("V:|[v0]|", views: signUpButton)
    loginContainerView.addConstraintWithFormat("H:|[v0]|", views: passwordResetButton)
    loginContainerView.addConstraintWithFormat("V:|[v0]|", views: passwordResetButton)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really like to replace rootViewController to other view controllers. I think it should stay as it is.

Why not make it like this?

```
yourTabBarController.presentViewController(loginViewController, 
                                   animated: animated,
                                 completion: nil)
```

This will show loginViewController on the top of your tabBarController. You could show it when user is not logged. But when the user press login and the login succeeded, you can show the main screen by using:

```
loginViewController.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true)
```

Comment: I like the premise of not changing the rootViewController. When I add this I get the error: "Use of instance member 'presentViewController' on type 'UIViewController'; did you mean to use a value of type 'UIViewController' instead?" What does this mean / how do I fix it?

Comment: How do you call `presentViewController`? Could you write it here?

Comment: Don't call it like this `UITabBarController.presentViewController` it's wrong, You have to call it like this: `tabBarController.presentViewController` where `tabBarController` is your initialized tab bar controller

Comment: I'm not understanding this very well. I tried:

**let tabBarController = CustomTabBarController()
tabBarController.presentViewController(SignInViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)**

Cannot convert value of type 'SignInViewController.Type' to expected argument type 'UIViewController'

Comment: initialize first like this, `let signInVC = SignInViewController()`, then `tabBarController.presentViewController(signInVC, animated: true, completion: nil)`

Answer (score 0):

The typical thing to do is to check if the user needs login in `applicationDidFinish...` and then to set the `window.rootViewController` to the login VC if they need it and the starting VC if they don't

On correct login, the app should set the window rootViewController to whatever you want to start the app.

The VC stack should be a clean representation of what you want on there -- so either a login flow or the app, but not both.

Comment: A problem I'm getting with setting the rootViewController to the SignInViewController is
"Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'UICollectionView must be initialized with a non-nil layout parameter'"